# Find GPS accuracy of track using gpx data

Tags: python, gps, coordinates, latitude-longitude, gpx

I have a bunch of gpx files, where tracks of around 500 (+/- 50) meters were saved. I compared the tracks to the measuring wheel distance and have calculated the relative error through them.
Now, out of 50 tracks, around 10 have a distance error (sum of Vincenty distance between each (lon,lat) recorded) > 5% (up to 16%) and i want to find possible causes for the error using only the gpx data.
My goal is to see, if it is possible to determine gps distance accuracy through the gpx data i have, without comparing to the measuring wheel.
I have heard of Dilution of Precision etc. but i don't know how many satellites are being used each time or the distance to the location etc.
Any possibilities? I can't find similarities in these track, that lower error tracks don't also have.
I'm also using python.

Approaches: check elevation inaccuracy compared to kalman filtered elevation, smooth track using moving average and compare to kalman filtered track (makes a difference, but the curvier the track, the worse it performs), find correlations between filtered and raw data... doesn't show much of a difference to 1% error tracks. I have also used speed recordings of each point to use distance = speed*time but the distance was overestimated by more than a 100 m.

Comment: Only 4 satellites are used for calculation. Good GPS devices just check the set of 4 satellites with lower DOP. A youtuber (standupmaths) did a "similar" work with xmas tree: https://github.com/standupmaths/xmastree2021: try to discover anomalies automatically, just because some time one or more points are at wrong distance). You can get inspired by that. Or just calculate distance, speed, and direction of every point. Then discard when it is too much, or if it go backward.

Comment: the question needs sufficient code for a minimal reproducible example:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: bit late, but I'd suggest saving the raw NMEA data somewhere.  they provide access to horizontal and vertical errors which I've used in a kalman filter to track position.  it would be useful to include a few lines from the GPX file in question, the standard is pretty flexible so knowing what you actually have would help